# Expression for a linear operator

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations

Let $\mathcal{B}=\{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$,

where $b_1=(1,0,0); b_2=(1,1,0); b_3=(0,1,1)$.

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ a linear operator with matrix (respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}$) is given by

$$A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 3 & -4 & 2 \\ 1 & -2 & 2 \\ 1 & -5 & 5 \end{array}\right].$$

and let $x,y,z$ the coordinates of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}$.

The exercise asks to find the expression for $T(x,y,z)$.

Since the matrix is the matrix of $T$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ and since the coordinates are with respect to $\mathcal {B}$ to compute $T(x,y,z)$ is right say that

$T(x,y,z)=A(x,y,z)^T$?

Comment: Absolutely right. But then I think the exercise wants a more explicit expression, that is, wants you to explicitly compute that matrix-vector product.

Comment: "Find the expression for $T(x,y,z)$" - do you mean in basis $\mathcal{B}$ or in canonical basis? Your answer indeed gives coordinates of $T(x,y,z)$ in respect to $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So it is just $T(x,y,z)=(3x-4y+2z; x-2y+2z; x-5y+5z)$

Comment: Hi Abstraction, this is my doubt, the exercise ask me to find $T(x,y,z)$ and it is written that $(x,y,z)$ are the coordinates in respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}$ so I guess I should find $T(x,y,z)$ in respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}$ but I'm not sure.

Comment: There is no mention of any other basis, so you should give the expression of $T$ with coordinates in the basis $\mathcal{B}$, which is just, as you said, multiplying $A$ by $(x,y,z)^t$.

Comment: Mm, thinking on it, I would probably write: $$T(x,y,z)=(3x-4y+2z)e_1+(x-2y)e_2+(x-5y+5z)e_3,$$ and then expand it back to canonical basis. Writing $(3x-4y+2z,x-2y+2z,x-5y+5z)$ would mean w.r.t. canonical basis $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on whether you take $(a,b,c)$ to mean $ae_1+be_2+ce_3$ or $ae_1'+be_2'+ce_3'$, where the primed vectors are the canonical versors of $\mathbb{R}^3$, that is $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$. I personally had overlooked this, but to be sure I would write that $T(x,y,z)$ is $A(x,y,z)^T$ if by $(x,z,y)$ we mean a vector of coordinates with respect to $\mathcal{B}$, and then compute the expression $A(x,y,z)^T$, which is (as you noted in a comment) $(3x-4y+2z,x-2y+2z,x-5y+5z)$. Without specifying that vectors of coordinates are all given w.r.t. $\mathcal{B}$, someone very precise might complain that coordinate vectors to him/her are only in the canonical basis.

In fact, for that person $T(x,y,z)$ might mean "take map $T$ and apply it to $(x,y,z)$ where the coordinates are with respect to the canonical basis". Which would require computing a change of basis and changing the basis for $A$. BUt it seems very unlikely. After all, the canonical basis is never mentioned, so I guess it is safe enough just to assume coordinate vectors are always w.r.t. $\mathcal{B}$ in this exercise and its solution.

Bottom line: either you did right, or whoever says otherwise is being absurdly pernickety if you ask me :).